# Why jquery .data() method does not fetch updated value?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui-sortable, angular-ui-sortable

I implement sort of  FilePanels with folders and subfolders.

Visually from Chrome Developer Tools I can see that `ui.item.sortable.droptarget` has `data` attribute of `parent-folder-id == 2`, but when I try to access it in code (via jquery `data` method) it returns 10 (value of another folder's parent where I was recently).
Why it does not get updated? When I move to another folder - new value to `vm.parentId` is assigned based on server's value of that folder. DOM is updated correctly...

```
<ul ui-sortable="vm.sortableOptions"
        ng-model="vm.cache.items"
        data-parent-folder-id="{{vm.parentId}}">
```

[image]

---

**Added later**:
Even if I update .data() getter to `ui.item.sortable.droptarget.data("parentFolderId")` it still returns `10`

---

**Update 2: Added plunker demo:**
http://plnkr.co/edit/14XfBOTFuJZ0oSy2ozqh?p=preview

```
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="xxx" data-parent="{{parentId}}"></div>
    <button ng-click="getParentId()">Get Parent Id</button>
    <br>
    <button ng-click="setParentId(15)">Set Parent Id to 15</button>
    <br>
    <button ng-click="getParentId()">Get Parent Id</button>
    <br>
    {{parentId}}
  </body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $element) {

  activate();

  function activate() {
    $scope.parentId = 10;
  }

  $scope.setParentId = function(number) {
    $scope.parentId = number;
  }

  $scope.getParentId = function() {
    $scope.parentId = $($element).find('.xxx').data('parent');
  }

});
```

When you click buttons in this sequence: `Set - Get` - `data` value succesfully updates. But when you click in another sequence: `Get - Set - Get` - the same problem appears as in my previous code - after value was updated with new value when getting it - an old value returns.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery get HTML 5 Data Attributes with hyphens and Case Sensitivity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22753629/jquery-get-html-5-data-attributes-with-hyphens-and-case-sensitivity)

Comment: We have no idea how you produce that...not enough code shown. Create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: ok, cool - I will try to reproduce a problem in isolated example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's solution, inspired by this SO question:
[get wrong value in data attribute jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335833/get-wrong-value-in-data-attribute-jquery)

```
ui.item.sortable.droptarget.attr("data-parent-folder-id")
```

Basically what nasty jQuery does - it **caches** data value and then just returns old one... So a solution is to not use `data` method at all :)

It's a documented behaviour of .data(): 
http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

> The data- attributes are pulled in the first time the data property is
>   accessed and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all data values
>   are then stored internally in jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

In angularJs you don't really need to do all the jQuery stuff as the model is bound to the html element instantly.

Actually, with angularJs you don't even need jQuery at all.

You don't have to get the value of the property with `getParentId` as it is already shown in your `{{parentId}}`.

The property is scoped and lives in your controller `MainCtrl`.

To understand how the binding system really works you can play with this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/EcF4sTcV5cO0yuM6VbLu?p=preview).

As you can see, changing the value in the textbox changes the value of your `{{parentId}}` because of the data binding.

this is achieved `using ng-model="parentId"`

Comment: I know, angular magic binding is cool and all, but in my situation getting a `parentId` from `data` attribute will save me a week or two of refactoring a codebase. I would be glad to receive a parentId from model - but at a time of calling - I don't have it (I am operating inside third-party JS library)