# jQuery code not running when putting it on an if statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, data-url

I'm trying to execute a jQuery script to change the data-url attribute based on which radio button is clicked/selected.

But my code won't work when I put it inside the if statement to check which radio button is active. It will successfully replace the data-url attribute though when executing without an if statement.

```js
$('input[name="radio1"]').on('change', function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 'yearly') {
    var a = $('#samcart').data('url');
    $('#samcart').attr("data-url", "www.urlhere.com");
  } else if ($(this).val() == 'quarterly') {
    var a = $('#samcart').data('url');
    $('#samcart').attr("data-url", "www.url2here.com");
  } else {
    var a = $('#samcart').data('url');
    $('#samcart').attr("data-url", "www.url3here.com");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="samcart" class='samcart-popup-container' style='margin:auto;width:200px;align:center;' data-id='123' data-url='empty'>
  <div class='samcart-popup-button' type='button' class='btn btn-default css3button'>
    Join
  </div>
```

Comment: Hi Nardi, and welcome. Can you provide the code that comprises the `<input name="radio1" ...>`?

Comment: Hi Forty3, thank you! 

`<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="yearly" value="yearly"><label class="yearly-label four col" for="yearly">I have some text here</p></label>`

And two other radio buttons with yearly and quarterly values instead of monthly.

Comment: Where are the radio buttons in your HTML?

Comment: You shouldn't mix `.attr()` and `.data()` to access data attributes, maybe that's your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335833/get-wrong-value-in-data-attribute-jquery/28335905#28335905

Comment: @Barmar I kinda feared that, but how can I make it work since `$('#samcart').attr("data-url", "www.url3here.com");` was the only method that actually changed the data-url value

Comment: `$("#samcart").data("url", "www.url3here.com")` should work

Comment: Or `a = $("#samcart").attr("data-url");`. Just be consistent about it, use only `.data()` or `.attr()` for that attribute.

Comment: Really appreciate your answer @Barmar! However it's not working still. Driving me crazy. The problem seems to be in the if statement, since the code that sets the attribute works fine standalone

Comment: Can you add the buttons to the HTML in the question?

Comment: This is the only button. I have included it's code in the post above. 
`<div class='samcart-popup-button' type='button' class='btn btn-default css3button'>
        Join
      </div>` Here is it's default script provided that makes the payment gateway accesible https://samcart.com/assets/templates/popup/embed_scripts/embed.min.js

Comment: @Barmar Thanks dude, I resolved it in a different approach, but if you have found the solution to the old approach, you're welcome to share it

Comment: I can't find a solution because I don't understand why your code isn't working. You should post the solution you found as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**
It's seem your code is good, I do not substantial changes, see the jsfille below:

https://jsfiddle.net/7tL6dfft/16/

HTML

```
<form action='#' method='get'>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="yearly" value="yearly"><label class="yearly-label four col" for="yearly">I have some text here</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="quarterly" value="quarterly"><label class="yearly-label four col" for="yearly">quarterly</label>
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="weekly" value="weekly"><label class="yearly-label four col" for="yearly">weekly</label>

</form>
<a id="samcart" href='#' data-url='http://exmaple.com'>sam cart url</a>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
console.log("start");

$('input[type=radio][name=radio1]').on('change', function() {
  console.log("event",$(this).val());
  if ($(this).val() == 'yearly') {

    $('#samcart').data("url", "www.urlhere.com");
    $('#samcart').html("www.urlhere.com");
    var a = $('#samcart').data('url');
  } else if ($(this).val() == 'quarterly') {

    $('#samcart').data("url", "www.url2here.com");
    $('#samcart').html("www.url2here.com");
    var a = $('#samcart').data('url');
  } else {

    $('#samcart').data("url", "www.url3here.com");
    $('#samcart').html("www.url3here.com");
    var a = $('#samcart').data('url');
  }
  alert("new data-url: "+a);
});
})
```

May be you were mislead by

- your debug, you take the "var a" before change the value
- your browser, sometimes the change of attrs is not show by developer tool
- the position of the js, you set your JS before the code in the loading chain, see **$(function(){})**

Comment: Thanks but It's still not working. To clarify, I have used multiple methods for adding the if statements and I had no ideas left. None of them worked