# data attribute doesn't change when variable value is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

**THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE BECAUSE I USE `.data()` and NOT `.attr()` LIKE ATTACHED SUGGESTS**

I need to change a data attribute value when a variable is updated. I'm making a dropdown that ties to a discount field and I need to update both the text and the data attribute that is in the `<option>` tag.

The relevant pieces looks like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#plan-options").change(function() {
    var moneyAmount = $(this).find('option:selected').data('amount');
    $("#selected-price").text("$" + moneyAmount);
    $("#purchase-warning").toggle();
    $(".default-encouragement").toggle();
  });
});
```

`#plan-options` is a `<select>` tag with `<option>`s that have data-attributes.

after that:

```
...
let selected = $("select option:selected");
let selectedAmount = selected.data("amount");
let selectedStr = selected.text();
let amountOffMoney = (data.amount_off / 100).toFixed(2);
if (data.percent_off != null) {
    selectedAmount = selectedAmount * (100 - data.percent_off) / 100
} else if (data.amount_off != null) {
    selectedAmount = selectedAmount - amountOffMoney;
    // this variable doesn't update - why?
    $("select option:selected").data("amount", selectedAmount);
} else {
    alert("Someting wrong happened!");
    return;
}
```

The most relevant piece is here:

```
selectedAmount = selectedAmount - amountOffMoney;
$("select option:selected").data("amount", selectedAmount);
```

My expectation is that I assign `selectedAmount` a new value, and changing the data  attribute to `selectedAmount` should change to the new assignment but that is not happening. The value stays the same.

Is it because it's `let`? Is it a scoping issue?

FULL CODE SNIPPET:

```
$(function() {
  $("#plan-options").change(function() {
    var moneyAmount = $(this).find('option:selected').data('amount');
    $("#selected-price").text("$" + moneyAmount);
    $("#purchase-warning").toggle();
    $(".default-encouragement").toggle();
  });
});
...
jQuery(function ($) {
          $(document).on("click",'.apply_coupon', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let plan = $('select[name="plan"]').val();
            let coupon = $('input[name="coupon"]').val();
            $.get('/premium/coupon/', {
              coupon: coupon,
              plan: plan
            }, function (data) {
              console.log("got data from calling coupon api:", data)
              if (data.success) {
                //discounted amount display handling
                let selected = $("select option:selected");
                let selectedAmount = selected.data("amount");
                let selectedStr = selected.text();
                let amountOffMoney = (data.amount_off / 100).toFixed(2);
                if (data.percent_off != null) {
                  selectedAmount = selectedAmount * (100 - data.percent_off) / 100
                } else if (data.amount_off != null) {
                  selectedAmount = selectedAmount - amountOffMoney;
                  console.log(selectedAmount);
                  $("#plan-options option:selected").data("amount", selectedAmount);
                } else {
                  alert("Someting wrong happened!");
                  return;
                }

                let regex = /\d+\.*\d*/;
                let newStr = selectedStr.replace(regex, selectedAmount.toString());
                selected.text(newStr);

                $('.apply_coupon').text("Remove");
                $('.apply_coupon').addClass("remove_coupon").removeClass('apply_coupon');
                $('input[name="couponVerified"]').val(1);
                $('input[name="coupon"]').hide();
                $('.coupon-results').show();
                $('.coupon-results__code').text(data.name);
                $('.coupon-results__info').text("$" + amountOffMoney + " off " + data.duration);
                $("#selected-price").text("$" + selectedAmount);
              } else {
                alert(data.message);
              }
            })
          });

          $(document).on('click','.remove_coupon', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.get('/premium/coupon/remove/', function (data) {
              if (data.success) {
                //discounted amount reverting handling
                let selected = $("select option:selected");
                let selectedAmount = selected.data("amount");
                let selectedStr = selected.text();
                let regex = /\d+\.*\d*/;
                let newStr = selectedStr.replace(regex, selectedAmount.toString());
                selected.text(newStr);
                $('.remove_coupon').text("apply");
                $('.remove_coupon').addClass("apply_coupon").removeClass('remove_coupon');
                $('input[name="couponVerified"]').val(0);
                $('input[name="coupon"]').show();
                $('.coupon-results').hide();
                $("#selected-price").text("$" + selectedAmount);
              }
            });
          });
        });
```

Comment: How are you telling whether it has changed?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335833/get-wrong-value-in-data-attribute-jquery/28335905#28335905

Comment: How do you know it is the same, have you log the value after the change, like this: `console.log($("select option:selected").data("amount");`. Note, in the [docs](https://api.jquery.com/data/) says: _Using the data() method to update data does not affect attributes in the DOM. To set a data-* attribute value, use attr._

Comment: What is the value of data.percent_off when you reach the if?

Comment: If you *really* need to change a **data attribute** then you need to use `$().attr("data-amount", newval);`.  This is highly unlikely.  More likely you just need to change the data value in the way you have - but this **does *not* change the DOM**, so don't then read it from the DOM/look in the browser - read it using `$().data("amount");`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get wrong value in data attribute jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335833/get-wrong-value-in-data-attribute-jquery)

Comment: No, not a duplicate because I use `.data()`...?

Comment: @Shidersz the data attr just will not update. I did that and it throws the correct value but in the DOM inspector I can still see it's the same. So lost...

Comment: @kawnah `JQuery` saves the updated values internally when using `data()`, the DOM attribute isn't changed, as the documentation says.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are specifying variables `data.amount_off` and `data.percent_off` that are `undefined`? I'm assuming these are also supposed to be `data` attributes on the `<option>` tag? The below snippet calls a test function on change of the `select` box value, to trigger your value calculations using the `data` attributes. Please let me know if you have any questions. **Note that switching from the $15.00 `option` back to the default "Select" `option` and then back to the $15.00 `option` will update the `data-amount` value each time.**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#plan-options").change(function() {
    var moneyAmount = $(this).find('option:selected').data('amount');

    $("#selected-price").text("");
    $("#purchase-warning").toggle();
    $(".default-encouragement").toggle();

    // call code function below for testing
    if (moneyAmount > 0) {
      // Amount data attribute value on select
      console.log('current data-amount value: ' + moneyAmount);
      $("#selected-price").text("$" + moneyAmount);
      testDataAttr();
    }
  });
});

function testDataAttr() {
  let selected = $("#plan-options option:selected");
  let selectedAmount = selected.data("amount");
  let selectedAmountOff = selected.data("amount-off");
  let selectedPercentOff = selected.data("percent-off");
  let selectedStr = selected.text();
  let amountOffMoney = (selectedAmountOff / 100).toFixed(2);

  if (selectedPercentOff > 0) {

    selectedAmount = (selectedAmount * (100 - selectedPercentOff) / 100).toFixed(2);

  } else if (selectedAmountOff > 0) {

    selectedAmount = (selectedAmount - amountOffMoney).toFixed(2);
    $("#plan-options option:selected").data("amount", selectedAmount);

    // Log updated amount that was set on data-amount attr
    console.log('updated data-amount value: ' + selected.data("amount"));

  } else {
    alert("Someting wrong happened!");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="plan-options">
  <option value="">-Select-</option>
  <option value="" data-amount="15.00" data-amount-off="5.00" data-percent-off="">15.00</option>
</select>
<div id="selected-price"></div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry but updating the selector does not work. Shall I post the full code?

Comment: Sure, if you can post the full code that'd be great.

Comment: its posted now take a look and let me know

Comment: Ok. I see you posted more `JS`, are you able to provide sample `JSON` responses for your `Ajax` requests, along with some of the `HTML`?

Comment: Try changing `let selected = $("select option:selected");` to be `let selected = $("#plan-options option:selected");` and see if that makes a difference?

Comment: that doesn't do anything

Comment: Those variables are from stripe but that has nothing to do with what the problem is.

Comment: In my code snippet, you do see where it is setting the new `data-amount` value correct?

Comment: @kawnah just checking back in on this if you were ever able to get it working or see it working in the snippet above?