# How to access data attribute of dynamically created anchor tag jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, attributes, anchor

When trying to retrieve the "data" attributes of a dynamically created anchor element, the function is unable to navigate $this to the attributes.

I've tried to use 'attr()' and navigate using 'closest()' but I'm unable to progress into the attributes: NamedNodeMap.

```js
function populateDropdown(data) {
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  let anchorItem = $(' <a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="#" id = "imagingSelection" > Imaging < /a>');
  let anchorDivider = $('<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>');
  $("#typeSelection").append(anchorItem);
  $("#typeSelection").append(anchorDivider);

  for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let anchorItem = $(`<a id="anchor${i}" class="dropdown-item" href="#" 
           data-sensitivity:"${data[i].sensitivity}" data-specicifity:"${data[i].specicifity}" data-nnh:"${data[i].numberToHarm}">${data[i].name}</a>`)
    $("#typeSelection").append(anchorItem);
  }
}

//Deal with click on dynamic DOM anchor creation
$('body').on('click', 'a.dropdown-item', function() {
  console.log($(this));
});
```

The console shows k.fn.init [a#anchor1.dropdown-item], which when I expand I can see the attributes in NamedNodeMap that I want, but cannot find a way to access

Comment: Your `for` markup generation is invalid. `data-key:"value"` is wrong.

Comment: `$(this).data("sensitivity")` would get you the data value, *assuming* everything else is working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `=` after the `data-XXX` attributes, not `:`, e.g. `data-sensitivity="${data[i].sensitivity}"`.

Or you could use jQuery's method for creating elements.

Then use `.data()` to access the data attribute. jQuery won't actually put it in a DOM attribute; see [get wrong value in data attribute jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335833/get-wrong-value-in-data-attribute-jquery/28335905#28335905)

BTW, you misspelled "specificity".

```js
function populateDropdown(data) {
  data = JSON.parse(data);
  let anchorItem = $(' <a class="dropdown-item disabled" href="#" id = "imagingSelection" > Imaging < /a>');
  let anchorDivider = $('<div class="dropdown-divider"></div>');
  $("#typeSelection").append(anchorItem);
  $("#typeSelection").append(anchorDivider);

  for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    let anchroItem = $("<a>", {
      id: `anchor${i}`,
      "class": "dropdown-item",
      href: "#",
      data: {
        sensitivity: data[i].sensitivity,
        specicifity: data[i].specicifity,
        nnh: data[i].numberToHarm
      },
      text: data[i].name
    });
    $("#typeSelection").append(anchorItem);
  }
}

//Deal with click on dynamic DOM anchor creation
$('body').on('click', 'a.dropdown-item', function() {
  console.log($(this).data("sensitivity"));
});
```

Comment: That's brilliant thank you Barmar - and thanks for the typo heads up - that's what happens when you stare at a screen for too long!  #o/