# JQuery unable to change 2 data attribute in a row

Tags: html, jquery, attributes

I'm creating a JQuery dynamic selector (img for reference)

[image]

To change my letters shown, I'm using data-attributes to select which letter is active on each columns. I'm able to change my attributes correctly if I'm changing only one of my inputs, but when I try to change 2 of them (to activate one and deactivate the other), only one of them is actually modified. Here's the code I'm using:

```
 function nextOrangeInput(inputNumber, direction) {
    var activeInput = $('.input-orange[data-orange-input="' + inputNumber + '"][data-orange-active="true"]');
    
    var position = activeInput.data("orange-position");
    if (direction === "up") {
        if (activeInput.data("orange-first") === "true") {
            $('.input-orange[data-orange-input="' + inputNumber + '"][data-orange-last="true"]').attr('data-orange-active', "true");
        } else {
            position = position - 1;
            $('.input-orange[data-orange-input="' + inputNumber + '"][data-orange-position="' + position + '"]').attr('data-orange-active', "true");
        }
    } else if (direction === "down") {
        if (activeInput.data("orange-last") === "true") {
            $('.input-orange[data-orange-input="' + inputNumber + '"][data-orange-first="true"]').attr('data-orange-active', "true");
        } else {
            position = position + 1;
            $('.input-orange[data-orange-input="' + inputNumber + '"][data-orange-position="' + position + '"]').attr('data-orange-active', "true");
        }
    }
    $('.input-orange[data-orange-input="' + inputNumber + '"][data-orange-active="true"]').attr('data-orange-active', "false");
}
```

Comment: Since you changed the attribute of the first element to `true`, the second selector is matching that element and changing it back to `false`.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't mix use of `.attr()` and `.data()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28335833/get-wrong-value-in-data-attribute-jquery/28335905#28335905

Comment: Oh wow, yeah that was it thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Barmar said in the comment, Since Ichanged the attribute of the first element to true, the second selector is matching that element and changing it back to false